# was or has been

Tags: grammar, word-choice

1. Long before Covid-19, domestic violence was recognised by the World Health Organisation as a “global health problem of epidemic proportions”
   or
2. Long before Covid-19, domestic violence has been recognised by the World Health Organisation as a “global health problem of epidemic proportions”
   which one is correct?

I am sure that domestic violence is still consider as global heath problem so in that case  1) would be  wrong?

Comment: At some _specific point in time_, WHO officially  recognized it as a problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do the following to avoid passive voice and make the wording more powerful.

Long before COVID-19, the World Health Organisation recognized domestic violence as a “global health problem of epidemic proportions”.

To keep the original phrasing, consider the intent of *was* and *has been*. If you want to indicate that they made an official declaration at a particular point, then go with *was*. Otherwise, if you want to indicate that they continually made this point, *has been* would make sense.